# Import the desired cells or cell range from .xlsx file into R data.frame using readxl package range

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I am using readxl R package to read my .xlsx excel sheet, when I use range function, it shows me an error:

```
in read_excel("C:/Data/Digital/Actual.xlsx", range = "D11:E20",  :   
unused argument (range = "D11:E20")
```

My code is:

```
X <- read_excel("C:/Data/Digital/Actual.xlsx",range="D11:E20", col_names = FALSE, skip = 0)
```

Along with `readxl`, I have installed

```
library(cellranger)
library(Rcpp)
library(tibble)
library(tidyverse)
```

Also I am followin the guidelines stated in-
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/readxl.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re-installing package <("readxl")> from "Tools" -> "Install Packages" -> "Repository" was installing old version.

I took zip file "readxl_1.0.0.zip" from the below location and installed it "Tools" -> "Install Packages" -> "Package Archive File". This resolves the issue.

[version 1.0.0, readxl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readxl/index.html)